# MongoDB query in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, google-maps, twitter, tweets

I have read through several problems that's the same as mine but I still couldn't understand how to query MongoDB inside PHP as I am new to both platforms.

Here's my query in MongoDB

```
db.tweets.find({},{"coordinates.coordinates": 1});
```

My initial PHP code

```
$document = $collection->find({},{"coordinates.coordinates": 1});

foreach($document as $doc)
{
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

My code returns an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmaps_thesis\main.php on line 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$collection->find([],['coordinates.coordinates' => 1]);
```

PHP uses `[]` for object and array notation instead of JavaScript's `{}`

Comment: `[]` is array notation *only*, and you've still got a stray `}` at the end.

Comment: Just wanna clarify things. So whenever I query MongoDB inside PHP, all I have to do is just replace all the "{}" to "[]"?

Comment: @Sammitch, thats the Stack Overflow app for ya. crappy af when selecting stuff

Comment: @Karl, yes and change `:` to `=>`